# Wincache stops running, with PHP and IIS

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, php7

I'm running PHP 7.2.22, with Wincache 2.0.0.8 on IIS 8.5, Windows Server 2012 R2.  Everything runs well most of the time.  But about every few days, Wincache stops running.  PHP and everything else keeps running fine, and I only notice Wincache has stopped if I check the cache status, and see it's not storing any queries (mainly to take some load off MySQL).  Then I get it going again by restarting IIS.  Then it is great for a few more days.

Any ideas as to what to do to stop the error?  I can set up a daily batch file to restart IIS early in the morning, but I'd rather try to solve it first, before working around it.

I see this in the error log and I see this, but it doesn't help me understand what the actual source of the problem is.  I don't see any English error information anywhere.

```
Faulting application name: php-cgi.exe, version: 7.2.22.0, time stamp: 0x5d664a16
Faulting module name: php_wincache.dll, version: 2.0.0.8, time stamp: 0x5a2044e3
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000001339a
Faulting process id: 0x1dac
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8880af85afbf4
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php-cgi.exe
Faulting module path: c:\program files (x86)\php\ext\php_wincache.dll
Report Id: 094f751f-f3ff-11ec-811c-00155dc3e5e6
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

These are my wincache settings:

```
wincache.apppoolid  no value 
wincache.chkinterval    30
wincache.debuglevel 0
wincache.enablecli  Off
wincache.fcachesize 24
wincache.fcenabled  On
wincache.fcenabledfilter    no value
wincache.fcndetect  On
wincache.filecount  4096
wincache.filemapdir no value
wincache.ignorelist no value
wincache.localheap  0
wincache.maxfilesize    256
wincache.namesalt   no value
wincache.reroute_enabled    Off
wincache.scachesize 8
wincache.ttlmax 1200
wincache.ucachesize 8
wincache.ucenabled  On
```

These are my Fast CGI settings:

```
Instance MaxRequests  200
Max Instances  0
Activity Timeout  150
Idle Timeout  300
Queue Length  1000
Rapid Fails PerMinute  10
Request Timeout 250
```

Comment: You are running an obsolete version, as PHP 7.2 has reached end of life a while ago, https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php Besides, Microsoft no longer supports PHP 8.x under its own support policies, so you should seriously migrate your PHP apps away from Windows.

Comment: Lex, As I don't want to learn to an entire new OS and web server, I prefer to stay with Windows and therefore with PHP 7.  It may be obsolete, but it works fine most of the time.  The question is how to get it working without changing the entire system.  I could upgrade to 7.3 or 7.4 if that's known to solve it, but I don't want to guess and find that Wincache may no longer work at all (?).

Comment: “Supported” means an active user base around it and maintenance from the developers, so a question can never be answered if the setup is rare (but your attitude sounds like that you are well prepared).